# C# Include List<> with object to Json result

Tags: c#, json, list

I have this Models:

Agenda

```
 public class Agenda
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgendaID { get; set; }
        public DateTime data { get; set; }
        public List<Agendamento> agentamentos { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

Agendamento

```
public class Agendamento
{
    [Key]
    public int AgendamentoID { get; set; }
    public Clientes cliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime data { get; set; }
    public string botijao { get; set; }
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
    public string veiculo { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

My DAOs:

AgendaDAO

```
 public class AgendaDAO
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public List<Agenda> Listar()
    {
        return db.Agenda.Include(a => a.agentamentos).ToList();
    }
}
```

AgendamentoDAO

```
public class AgendamentoDAO
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public List<Agendamento> Listar()
    {
        return db.Agendamentoes.Include(a => a.cliente).ToList();
    }
}
```

In my ApiController, I have this methods:

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    // GET: Api/ListarAgenda
    public ActionResult ListarAgenda()
    {
        AgendaDAO adao = new AgendaDAO();

        return Json(adao.Listar(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // GET: Api/ListarAgendamento
    public ActionResult ListarAgendamento()
    {
        AgendamentoDAO adao = new AgendamentoDAO();

        return Json(adao.Listar(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

My Json results:

Api/ListarAgenda

```
    [
  {
    "AgendaID": 13,
    "data": "/Date(1476327600000)/",
    "agentamentos": [],
    "status": null
  },
  {
    "AgendaID": 14,
    "data": "/Date(1476669600000)/",
    "agentamentos": [],
    "status": null
  }
]
```

Api/ListarAgendamento

```
    [
      {
        "AgendamentoID": 72,
        "cliente": {
      "ClientesID": 1007,
      "Nome": "Maria Zilda",
      "CPF": "00124794321",
      "Telefone": 30198269,
      "Estado": "PR",
      "Cidade": "Curitiba",
      "Rua": "Altevir De Souza Gonçalves",
      "Numero": 59,
      "Lat": "-25.3955309",
      "Long": "-49.2168943"
    },
    "data": "/Date(1476327600000)/",
    "botijao": "P13",
    "quantidade": 1,
    "veiculo": "VW Saveiro ",
    "status": null
  }]
```

My problem is: I need to see in my json result from Api/ListarAgenda the agendamentos list with clientes attributes. Something like this:

```
[
  {
    "AgendaID": 13,
    "data": "/Date(1476327600000)/",
    "agentamentos": [
      {
        "AgendamentoID": 72,
        "cliente": {
           "ClientesID": 1007,
           "Nome": "Maria Zilda",
           "CPF": "00124794321",
           "Telefone": 30198269,
           "Estado": "PR",
           "Cidade": "Curitiba",
           "Rua": "Altevir De Souza Gonçalves",
           "Numero": 59,
           "Lat": "-25.3955309",
           "Long": "-49.2168943"
          },
         "data": "/Date(1476327600000)/",
         "botijao": "P13",
         "quantidade": 1,
         "veiculo": "VW Saveiro ",
         "status": null
      }],
    "status": null
  }
]
```

"Include" is not working very well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using eager load right? You need to include cliente from each agendamento loaded

Comment: You mean, I need to do somethig like foreach .Add for agendamento list?

Comment: or you can use something like `.Include("agendamentos.cliente")`

Comment: just .Include("agendamentos.cliente") still showing "agentamentos": [],

Comment: Try `Include("agendamentos").Include("agendamentos.cliente")`